# Date transformation in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, date, transformation

I have a table with a date field, in DDL the ORDERDATE is set as date.

In the table the date looks like the below:

| ORDERDATE |
| --- |
| 2020-02-11 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-19 00:00:00 |
| 2020-10-27 00:00:00 |
| 2020-01-09 00:00:00 |

I would like to transform into MM/DD/YYYY, Ideally run an update on the table if possible?

I have tried:

```
SELECT to_date(to_char(trunc(OrderDate), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
FROM ORDER_TABLE;
```

but receive the error 'SQL Error [1843] [22008]: ORA-01843: not a valid month'

Help is much appreciated and I look forward to your responses and learning the error!

Many thanks,
AJ

Comment: A "date" in Oracle always has a time component. But your question is not even about that, it is about how to **display** dates. To change how your dates are displayed, change the parameter that controls that: `alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy'` Note that some interface programs store your preferences separately, so you will have to find that in your software and make the change there. But, in all cases, it's a matter of controlling the display of dates, not of changing the data in the table.

Comment: `DATE` values do not have a format. So you can't change it to begin with

Comment: To clarify the distinction further (between "date" and "string representation of date for display purposes") - imagine your date is currently shown as 28-JAN-2021 and you prefer to show 01/28/21. They are the same ***date***, so they are stored identically in the database (in the **date** data type); only the displaying is different, and that is not controlled by the stored data, it is controlled by "conversion to string" parameters. If you want full control, instead of `select orderdate` you can write `select to_char(orderdate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')` and then you don't depend on any defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the ORDERDATE stored as DATE in the database, so the only thing you need it convert it back to character string when you are reporting it (if you want to see it formated nicely)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(OrderDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') FROM ORDER_TABLE;
```